# Expresiones regulares en Bash

Tags: linux, regex, bash

Estoy tratando de realizar un script en bash, que me valide un directorio usando expresiones regulares, lo que tengo es lo siguiente.

```
echo "Ingresa La ruta de tu directorio"
read ruta
if [ $ruta != '^/[a-zA-Z]$' ];then
    echo "No has ingresado una ruta valida, recuerda que la ruta inicia con /"
    echo " "
    continue
else
    if [ -d $ruta ]; then
        echo""
        echo "hey, ya tienes creado tu directorio, tal vez necesites usar otra opcion"
        continue
    fi
fi
```

Cuando ingreso documents la validación funciona, pero al ingresar por ejemplo `/Documents` que es un directorio existente, el funcionamiento es igual y no valida la expresión es como si no ingresará el `/`.

¿Como podría validar correctamente la expresión?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Para comprobar una expresión regular en bash, debes usar el operador [`=~`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/RegularExpression) y debe colocarse entre *[doble brackets](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/031)* `[[ ]]`,

Ademas para hacer [mas compatible entre versiones](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Patterns#line-141) el script deberías colocar la expresión regular entre comillas simple en una variable previamente. (Gracias @TomFenech)

En cuanto a tu expresión regular debes agregar un `+` o `*` después de `[a-zA-Z]` ya que si no lo haces, captura un solo caracter y tu quieres capturar todos. (usa `*` si la el valor `/` sola es valido)

El IF quedaría así:

```
regla='^/[a-zA-Z]+$'
if [[ ! $ruta =~ $regla ]]
```

Este es un ejemplo simplificado:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Ingresa La ruta de tu directorio"
read ruta

regla='^/[a-zA-Z]+$'
if [[ ! $ruta =~ $regla ]]; then
 echo "Tiene la barra"
else
 echo "Falta la barra"
fi
```

Comment: No hace falta escapar la barra en este contexto. Has usado `'` en tu primer ejemplo pero no en el segundo; la forma sin `'` es la correcta. Más compatible sería introducir un variable `re='^\/[a-zA-Z]+$'` y luego usar `[[ ! $ruta =~ $re ]]`.

Comment: Gracias, no lo habia notado, algo de copia y pega creo. por lo demas, con mas compatible te refieres a que es mas portable?

Comment: Quería decir que funciona mejor entre versiones distintas de Bash. Puedes informarte en el [Bash Wiki](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Patterns) (enlace en inglés) en la sección "Regular Expressions".

Answer (score 1):

no es necesario declararlo, puede ser directo:

```
if [[ "tu_cadena" =~ "regex" ]]; then
```

Ejemplo:

```
if [[ "hola" =~ "^[Hh]" ]]; then
    printf "Empieza con h\n"
end
```

Puedes ver más acerca del regex en [regex101.com](https://regex101.com)

Comment: Si funciona (con algunas versiones), pero como explica el link que hay en mi respuesta, ponerlo en una variable es por motivos de compatibilidad entre versiones de bash ... "The best way to always be compatible is to put your regex in a variable and expand that variable in [[ without quotes, as we showed above.".

Answer (score 0):

Creo que lo has puesto al revés. Primero verifica si el usuario a introducido la / y si no le mandas al else if. Te dejo el codigo modificado. Lo he probado y a mi me funciona.

```
    read -p "Ingresa La ruta de tu directorio " ruta

if [ -d $ruta ]
then
     echo " "
     echo "hey, ya tienes creado tu directorio, tal vez necesites usar otra opcion"
     continue
elif [ $ruta != '^/[a-zA-Z]$' ]
then
   echo""
echo "No has ingresado una ruta valida, recuerda que la ruta inicia con /"
                continue
fi
```