# Error de ejecucion en el script

Tags: bash

Soy nuevo en bash, intento hacer un ejercicio que vi en internet pero presento los siguientes errores.

> validaciones.sh: línea 25: [[hfgh!=^[A-Za-z]$]]: orden no encontrada
>
> validaciones.sh: línea 28: [[54645!=^[0-9]{3}$]]: orden no encontrada

Busque y edite bastante el archivo en vano. Realmente no se que estoy haciendo mal, lo que si noto es que el regex me lo cambia. Es decir... yo pongo algo en el codigo pero en el stderr me marca algo distinto en el trozo del regex.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Practicar validaciones con bash
# Autor: By Retr0

# Init values
name=""
age=0
email=""
password=""

# Regex data
nameRegex='^[A-Za-z]$'
ageRegex='^[0-9]{3}$'
extractUserRegex='[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+@gmail\.com'
 
getData(){
    read -p "Ingresa tu nombre: " name
    read -p "Ingresa tu edad: " age
    read -p "Ingresa tu correo electronico: " email
    read -s -p "Ingresa tu contraseña: " password
}

validate(){
    if [[$name!=$nameRegex]]; then
        echo -e "\nNo puedes usar numeros o simbolos como nombre."
    else
        if [[$age!=$ageRegex]]; then
            echo -e "\nSolo puedes poner hasta 3 digitos, solo se aceptan numeros."
        fi
        echo -e "\nDatos validados con exito."
    fi
}

main(){
    # Run script
    getData && validate    
}

main
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes que cambiar la condición ya que estás utilizando expresiones regulares:

**Por lo que esto**:

```
if [[$name!=$nameRegex]]; then
```

**Pasaría a esto**:

```
if [[ ! $name =~ $nameRegex ]]; then
```

**Al igual que**:

```
if [[$age!=$ageRegex]]; then
```

**A esto**:

```
if [[ ! $age =~ $ageRegex ]]; then
```

Luego, creo que lo mejor es que cambies la expresión regular, por ejemplo

**De**:

```
nameRegex='^[A-Za-z]$'
```

**A**:

```
nameRegex='^[A-Za-z]+$'
```

El signo + que he añadido es un cuantificador que hace que haga match si se repite una letra de a-z o A-Z una o más veces. Sino, te haría match solo cuando inserte el usuario como nombre una sola letra.

** Código final**:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Practicar validaciones con bash
# Autor: By Retr0

# Init values
name=""
age=0
email=""
password=""

# Regex data
nameRegex='^[A-Za-z]+$'
ageRegex='^[0-9]{3}$'
extractUserRegex='[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+@gmail\.com'

getData(){
    read -p "Ingresa tu nombre: " name
    read -p "Ingresa tu edad: " age
    read -p "Ingresa tu correo electronico: " email
    read -s -p "Ingresa tu contraseña: " password
}

validate(){
    if [[ ! $name =~ $nameRegex ]]; then
        echo -e "\nNo puedes usar numeros o simbolos como nombre."
    else
        if [[ ! $age =~ $ageRegex ]]; then
            echo -e "\nSolo puedes poner hasta 3 digitos, solo se aceptan numeros."
        fi
        echo -e "\nDatos validados con exito."
    fi
}

main(){
    # Run script
    getData && validate
}

main
```

Comment: Por si sirve de ayuda, aquí tienes más info sobre expresiones regulares: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/4198/expresiones-regulares-en-bash